# windows store correct way of getting dispatcher, async

Tags: windows-store-apps, silverlight-5.0, dispatcher

I'm currently looking into both windows store apps & wp8 apps, both being sl and c# projects.

Fetching the dispatcher is different from wpf, and I'm a bit pussled as the one in Window.Current seems to disappear in some of my async methods.

All I could do was basicly just to put a propery in the App class, but it seems so unsafe, I don't follow the logics here.

I'll post an example:

```
internal class MainviewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
 ..............
    private async void GetLastDocumetAsync()
    {
            // Window.Current is null here, but not outside async!
            await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ObservableCollection<ScannedDocument> docs = await ServiceLocator.DocumentClient.GetLastScannedDocumentsAsync();                    
                ScannedDocuments.AddRange(docs);
                SelectedDocument = ScannedDocuments.LastOrDefault();
            }
    }
    ...
    public void SomeMethod(){
        // Window.Current is not null
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetLastDocumetAsync());

    }
}
```

When SomeMethod() is called, Window.Current is not null. When we're in the async method, and I need the dispatcher, it's null.

Any pointers?

Brgds,

polkaextremist

Comment: Silverlight in Windows Store?

Answer (score 2):

First, I strongly recommend as much as possible to restructure your code so that explicit capturing and restoring of the context isn't necessary. As long as you just use plain `async` and `await`, you won't need to capture the context at all.

In your example code, there's no need for `StartNew`, so you could do something like this:

```
private async Task GetLastDocumentsAsync()
{
    ObservableCollection<ScannedDocument> docs = await ServiceLocator.DocumentClient.GetLastScannedDocumentsAsync();                    
    ScannedDocuments.AddRange(docs);
    SelectedDocument = ScannedDocuments.LastOrDefault();
}

public async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
    await GetLastDocumentsAsync();
    ...
}
```

If you really *do* need to explicitly capture a context, I recommend you use `SynchronizationContext`. You can think of it sort of like a cross-platform `Dispatcher`; I have more info in [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).